# How to uninstall expired Kasperksky without required password?

Tags: uninstall, kaspersky

My colleage's PC has Kaspersky software that is expired. And he want to remove the software - I help him to uninstall it but the software requires some password that nether of us knows what it is.

A software should be able to be removed by the PC's administrator so I ask here to look for such workaround. My [quick google search for this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=uninstall%20expired%20kasperksky%20but%20require%20password) seems not helpful at all.

Please share if you know how to.

Comment: [Here](http://support.kaspersky.com/10293)’s the relevant support article which can be found extremely easily by search for “kaspersky uninstall password”.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Though that is about asking Kasperskylab. I don't think so. We own our Windows and our PC and we have admin access. We should be able to remove any unwanted software.

Comment: If you own the PC, you can always reinstall Windows. Kaspersky is designed to withstand tampering. Your colleague (or whoever set the password) is to blame here. It’s surprising enough there’s any regular way around it.

Answer (score 23):

1. Boot in Safe Mode
2. open regedit

> go to Windows 64-bit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\KasperskyLab\AVP16.0.1\settings
>
> change EnablePswrdProtect to 0

3. restart in normal mode
4. set a new password for Kasperky (require even if you want to uninstall)
5. uninstall Kasperky

Comment: worked! in my case the registry path was HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\KasperskyLab\Products\settings

Comment: worked like a charm

Comment: Remember to mark as answer @bgmCoder

Comment: I can't mark it - I am not the OP, sorry; but I gave you an upvote!

Comment: I was able to remove the password by following first two steps but as soon as I rebooted into normal mode, the password was back again. So I uninstalled Kaspersksky from safe mode (after removing the password).

Comment: In my case the path seems to be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\KasperskyLab\protected\KES\policy\subItems\Product\settings

Answer (score 5):

What you will need to do is run the Kaspersky Anti-Virus remover. Please follow the steps below.

1. IMPORTANT: Please create a restore point on your system before using the tool by following these instructions:

   - Windows 7 & Vista:
     http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows7/create-a-restore-point
   - Windows 8/8.1:
     On the Start screen type restore point -> Click 'Create a Restore Point' -> Click 'Create' -> name the restore point Before KAV Remover.
2. Please use KAV remover to remove the Kaspersky product which was not removed with the steps above:

   Download the Kaspersky removal tool from:
   http://media.kaspersky.com/utilities/ConsumerUtilities/kavremvr.exe

   Choose the option to 'Save' the file, do not choose Run.
   Save it to a location that is easy for you to find; e.g.: your desktop.
   Follow the opening process of KAV and select the Kaspersky product you have installed, type in the Captcha code and continue to uninstall the Kaspersky product.

(Tips of the trade when working for Kaspersky!)

Source: https://support.kaspersky.com/1464#block1

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

1. Reboot into Safe Mode (hit F8 at startup and select safe mode)
2. Enter the Kaspersky Program Folder and locate the avp.exe
3. rename the avp.exe to whatever you desire (i.e. temp.exe)
4. double-click that exe - the Kaspersky icon should show up on the taskbar at the bottom right screen
5. right-click that icon and select Settings
6. Now find the passwort protection and turn it off
7. Click ok to close the window and restart your computer
8. Now take the usual steps to uninstall software (control panel -> uninstall programs -> kaspersky and follow the routine)

Comment: Thanks @Andre - I'll try your suggestion and back with you later.

Comment: This method doesn't work anymore. It still asks for password when saving settings change. The solution from @Bento-Fernandes worked tho.

Answer (score 2):

Use Revo Uninstaller Software. It will remove entire software from root including registry and log files.
URL: [www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have forgotten your Kaspersky password here is the best way to change it under Windows 7.

1. Visit this link https://support.kaspersky.com/us/11101. Download the KLAPR zip setup.
2. Press Windows + R for the Run window and Type msconfig and click Ok.
3. On the System Configuration Dialogue box click on "Boot option" under menu.
4. Under Boot options select safe mode with minimal as the second selection.
5. Click Ok. On the next dialogue box click Restart. (This will boot in safe mode)
6. Under safe mode; visit the folder containing the KLAPR setup, Unzip and Double click. This will open a command dialogue box. Just press any key and it will show process successful. press any button again as instructed and restart.(The computer will restart in safe mode)
7. Open Kaspersky and you will notice you can now change the password.
8. Repeat step 2 while in safe mode but this time UNCHECK the safe mode option and restart your computer.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Download Kaspersky Removal Tool.

- Enter safe mode (msconfig → reboot into Safe Mode)
- Regedit → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> → search for EnablePswrdProtect → change in 3 places for zero.

Still in safe mode, run Kaspersky Removal Tool.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1051956/213131) by Bento Fernandes works, but for me it was slight different:

I found the **EnablePswrdProtect** entry in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\KasperskyLab\protected\KES10SP1\settings
```

And I didn't need to change the password to uninstall it.

Answer (score -1):

***Problem Statement:*** I have Kaspersky Endpoint Security installed by an org. I will need to delete the license before proceeding to uninstall it. But while deleting the license, I am asked for a password, which I am not aware of since it's decided by the org. In order to prevent the password prompt from popping, you could do the following:

In Windows 11,

1. Enter Safe Mode.
   Refer to [how-to-enter-safe-mode-win-11](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-11/how-to-boot-safe-mode-in-windows-11/m-p/2764802) if you do not know how to enter.
2. Open Registry Editor. Locate HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\KasperskyLab\
3. For each of the folders/items, click, expand, and check if you can see a key entry on the RHS by the name **'EnablePswrdProtect'**. Modify all their values to **0**. It's important you go through all such entries and modify them all one by one.
4. This will only make sure you don't receive the password prompt when you are trying to delete the license. You will still see 'uninstall' being *disabled* in 'Add or Remove Programs'.
5. Restart your system. This will exit Safe Mode.
6. Now, open Kaspersky and navigate to the page where you can **delete** the license. Proceed to delete the license.
7. Go to 'Add or Remove Programs', and click on the three dots located adjacent to the name 'Kaspersky'. Click **'Modify'** since 'Unistall' would still be disabled. Here in the prompt, you will be able to 'Uninstall'.

We need to enter Safe Mode since otherwise you will not be allowed to modify Registry entries. Keep in mind that you don't meddle with any other Registry entries as this may cause unintentional side effects.